# How to scan a directory to list all sub folders not files

Tags: 7, files

I have a folder (root folder) with thousands of sub folders and `*.json` files inside sub folders. How can I get list of sub folder names inside folder (root folder) using [`file_scan_directory`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_scan_directory/7.x)?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use RecursiveDirectoryIterator for that.

```
$path = '/your/awesome/absolute/path';
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);
$json_files = new RegexIterator($dir, '/\.json$/');
foreach ($json_files as $file) {
  // Do you stuff here.
  echo "$file";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If [`file_scan_directory`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_scan_directory/7.x) usually returns directories then perhaps you can use the regex mask to search for names that don't have a dot (.) in them.

There are very few files in a Drupal installation that don't have an extension, and I imagine there will be none in your folder structure if all it contains is .json files...

```
file_scan_directory($your_root_folder, '/^[^\.]+$/');
```

The above *should* match all items in the directory structure that don't contain a dot, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105956/regex-does-not-contain-certain-characters).

Comment: It seems that `file_scan_directory()` does not return directories, so this won't work.